# Is it possible to swap 2 hard drives and keep OS running without formatting?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, swap

Recently I bought an SSD drive (Samsung Evo 860 250GB) and installed it in place of the DVD drive (SATA II 3.0Gb/s). I removed the DVD drive. Then I used Samsung Magician and copied the HDD drive to the SSD drive. Everything works perfectly. But now I would like to swap the HDD with SSD because currently my SSD can reach a maximum of 250 MB/s where according to the specification this SSD can reach 550 MB/s. 
Can I swap the hard drives and keep Windows running normally? (I have windows 10 installed). Or do I have to format the drives and install the OS again?

Comment: As long as you change the drive/boot order in BIOS/UEFI it should work. But don't expect any improvement if you have SATA II only.

Comment: I have a SATA III connection (where currently the HDD is installed). So I should expect a high improvement. Right?

Comment: Indeed, you should expect the maximum speed for that drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use the DVD connection for your main disk.
You would get much better performance if you exchange the placements (and connectors)
of the two drives.

If the SSD is a good bootable copy of the HDD, then you wouldn't (hopefully)
even need to change anything in the BIOS or to re-install the operating system.

Comment: Yes I didn't know that back then. First I used the Rapid mode which uses 2 GB from Ram and I had a constant 550 MB/s as read and write. But since I have only 6GB Ram and use Photoshop and Illustrator and few other programs at the same time, I had to disable the Rapid mode. There where I realized that I can achieve a maximum of 250 MB/s.

Comment: Great!! Just swapped the two hard drives. Windows booted perfectly without any problems. The Read speed has doubled and write speed is now at 337 MB/s. Even at the manufactures homepage they say that the write speed is 520 MB/s.
Random (IOPS) : 
Read : 48,828
Write : 41,503 
according to Samsung Magician Software. 
Any Idea how to get the 520 MB/s write speed? or is this value only in theory and not real life situations?

Comment: Yes, it's theoretical, there isn't much you can do to improve upon it.